# Treat every node in SpriteKit Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit

Every time I click the screen I make a new SKShapeNode of a circle.

I tried to make the next thing: Whenever the new SKShapeNode get under the ground (the ground y is half of the screen) - he becomes green.
So I tried this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
newestBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
        newestBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: newestBall.frame.height / 2)
        newestBall.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) ,y: self.frame.size.height - newBall.frame.height)
        newestBall.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        newestBall.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        newestBall.glowWidth = 1.0
        newestBall.zPosition = 9
        newestBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        newestBall.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        newestBall.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        newestBall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        newestBall.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        newestBall.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        newestBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballsGroup
}
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
if newestBall.position.y < ground.position.y {
            newestBall.fillColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        }
}
```

And it works! BUT whenever I click twice and create 2 balls (and the first ball still didn't make it under the ground) only the last ball becomes green because he is `newestBall`.

I want to make every ball green if he gets under the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `newestBall` a name:

```
newestBall.name = "Ball"
```

Then check throught all nodes with name = "Ball" and change color ir requirements ar met

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("Ball", usingBlock: {
        (node: SKNode!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        let shapeNode = node as! SKShapeNode
        if shapeNode < self.ground.position.y {

            shapeNode = SKColor.greenColor()
        }
    })
```

You can add that to `update()`. `self` is `parentNode` or your newestBall and ground nodes.

Comment: it gives me this error:
'(SKShapeNode!, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void' is not convertible to '(SKNode, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void'. When I tried to change the `SKShakenode` to `SKNode` it gave me another error at the line of `node = SKColor.greenColor()`:  Cannot assign a value of type 'UIColor' to a value of type 'SKNode!'

Comment: CORRECT! Thank you! Just add } after the `shapeNode = SKColor.greenColor()` line to close the if statement. And add .fillColor to this line of code: `shapeNode = SKColor.greenColor()`